# Why am I not seeing any speedup from the multithreading in this program?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, debugging, pthreads

I have this function. It recursively calculates an arena under a curve. It's running on computer with two cores.

```
void* quad(void* argis){
    struct args* arg=argis;

    double m=(arg->l+arg->r)/2;
    double fm=func(m);
    double larea=(arg->fl+fm)*(m-arg->l)/2;
    double rarea = (fm+arg->fr)*(arg->r-m)/2;

    struct args* arg1 = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    arg1->l=arg->l;
    arg1->r=m;
    arg1->fl=arg->fl;
    arg1->fr=fm;
    arg1->area=larea;

    struct args* arg2 = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    arg2->l=m;
    arg2->r=arg->r;
    arg2->fl=fm;
    arg2->fr=arg->fl;
    arg2->area=rarea;

    if(fabs((larea+rarea)-arg->area)>error){
        if(threads<=1){
            void* p1=quad(arg1);
            void* p2=quad(arg2);
            larea=*((double*)p1);
            rarea=*((double*)p2);
            free(p1);
            free(p2);


        }
        else{
            pthread_t thread1, thread2;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            threads-=2;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

            pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &quad, (void*)arg1);
            pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &quad, (void*)arg2);

            void* ptr1;
            void* ptr2;

            pthread_join(thread1,&ptr1);
            pthread_join(thread2,&ptr2);


            larea=*(double*)ptr1;
            rarea=*(double*)ptr2;

        }
    }
    free(arg1);
    free(arg2);

    double ret= (larea+rarea);
    double* poin=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    *poin=ret;

    return poin;
}
```

Now when I set the `threads` variable to `2` it should create two new threads that does the recursion concurrently, I think this does just that, I get a sane estimation of Pi however it's not any faster than just running on one thread (setting `threads` to 1), in fact it's somewhat slower.

Why isn't it twice as fast? Any help sorting this out would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think splitting into threads will speed up your code? How do you benchmark? Which platform? Where is the [mcve]? Oh, and don't cast `void *` in C!

Comment: Programming is hard.

Comment: Undefined behavior for non-readonly, non-atomic, unsynchronized access to a shared object from multiple threads.

Comment: Not quite seeing it.  Which object is shared and requires synchronization?

Comment: @JohnWu: Look at `if(threads<=1)` and `pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            threads-=2;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);`. `threads` is accessed *without* taking the lock in one case, so the lock does not prevent the race.

Comment: Don't think that is an issue when `threads` is set to 1 or 2, which are the two cases described by the OP.  If it is 1 then there is no multithreading.  if it is 2, it is reduced to 0 before the threads are spawned, and never modified from within one of the spawned threads.  But you're right, if it is set to 4 or higher there could be an issue.  Doesn't explain the performance profile of the code, which is the question at hand.

Comment: @JohnWu: Is there a reason why you don't address me directly by "@EOF" in your comments? It'd make responding a lot easier. Anyway, there is undefined behavior in the code, as well as memory leaks, access to static objects and vastly too much memory allocation. That's just in the (inadequate) part of the code that was actually *posted*. I consider SMT one of the least likely culprits for the performance of this code.

Comment: @EOF: Thanks, please post more details on the undefined behavior, memory leaks, static object access and excessive allocation.  Do you agree we have addressed the lack of synchronization on `threads`?

Comment: @JohnWu: No. I voted to *close the question*, since the question cannot be answered as-is. There is *way* too much missing context.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a sufficiently large problem for multithreading?  Maybe the overhead of creating new threads and managing locks is greater than the cost of solving the problem with a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your processor may have multiple cores, but what about your [floating point coprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit)?  It probably does not, and will block each thread while the other thread is performing FPU computations.

Also, see this article:

> Workloads that do not benefit much from simultaneous multithreading are those in which the majority of individual software threads use a large amount of any resource in the processor or memory. For example, **workloads that are floating-point intensive are likely to gain little from simultaneous multithreading and are the ones most likely to lose performance.** These workloads heavily use either the floating-point units or the memory bandwidth. Workloads with low CPI and low cache miss rates might see a some small benefit.

[Source](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/smt.htm)

Comment: Your link has a nice picture of "An Intel 80287" but doesn't each core now have its own FPU?

Comment: Think that depends on the core, doesn't it?  If only the OP had provided that information.

Comment: There are *many* other problems in the code that are *much* more likely to cause this. Note that the citation you provide talks about SMT, which doesn't even apply at all if the "two cores" from the OP's question are *physical cores* rather than *logical cores*.

Comment: Maybe.  Write an answer and list the problems, and we can discuss.

Comment: @JohnWu: I've already pointed out undefined behavior in a comment on the question itself. No point arguing about the performance of code that exhibits undefined behavior.